# Abstracting UIViewController like Cocoa ones

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller

EDIT: Is there someone that have some useful links about this topic? I mean good practices for writing reusable code and "abstraction"?

tl;dr - Read this comment [Abstracting UIViewController like Cocoa ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680074/creating-an-uiviewcontroller-for-similar-functionalities#comment27522090_18681446)

I have 3 `UITableViewController`:

- `CategoriesViewController`
- `RecipesViewController`
- `IngredientsViewController`

They're ordered hierarchically. Below an example of the hierarchy:

- Dessert (category)

  - Brownie (recipe)

    - Milk (ingredient)
    - Chocolate (ingredient)
    - Butter (ingredient)

[image]

Each one of these has similar functionalities with the others.
For example they all have sorting (moving rows), deleting, adding (presenting a modal view) etc.

Currently I've repeated all the code for every view controller customizing the parts that are related to each one. For example they all have an instance variable like this:

`CategoriesViewController.m`:

```
@implementation CategoriesViewController {
    NSMutableArray *categories;
}
```

`RecipesViewController.m`:

```
@implementation RecipesViewController {
    NSMutableArray *recipes;
}
```

`IngredientsViewController.m`:

```
@implementation IngredientsViewController {
    NSMutableArray *ingredients;
}
```

Because I think there's a better way to organize this view controller I've tried to create a skeleton of `MyListViewController.h`:

```
@interface MyListViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *list;

@end
```

`MyListViewController.m`:

```
@implementation MyListViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_list count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ListCell"];

    id currentObject = [_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentObject valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // get item to delete
        id object = [_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // remove it from list
        [_list removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // call callback
        [self didFinishDeletingItem:object];

        // delete row from tableview
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (void)didFinishDeletingItem:(id)item
{
}
```

In this way, once I've subclassed it I have only to assign `list` ivar to my data structure. And I can even override methods like `didFinishDeletingItem:` for customizing the behavior of each controller.

Because it's the first time that I would use best practices of writing and organizing code in this way I would love to know your opinions AND which are the best ways to **abstract** classes for reusing them following correctly the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This should be comment, but I can't comment yet).
Don't do
    [_list count];
Use the property:
    [self.list count]
Only access the ivar in the accessors, or you will get bitten somewhere along the line. This also goes for the other places you are using _list instead of self.list.

Your skeleton class looks OK and this is good coding. Extending on this: if the only thing later in that is different in the actual data for the items, you can create different subclasses of UITableViewCell. The the MyListViewController can see what type of objects are contained in the NSArray (or you can set a flag on MyListViewCOntroller) and use the appropriate UITableViewCell based on that (and hence display the data correctly.)

Comment: You said that "MyListViewController can see what type of objects are contained in the NSArray" but I don't want to hardcode the if-statements for each of the `UITableViewCell` type. I wish to make `MyListViewController` as abstract as possible to reuse it whenever I want and WITHOUT making changes in the class itself. I think that's the way that Cocoa-Touch classes are created. You can't see the implementation of those classes but you can use them for almost every situation thanks to their abstraction.

Comment: True. But this requires the data to be presented in the same way. If you want have the presentation depend on the data, you would need to inspect the data. Nonetheless, you are right.

Comment: Thanks man. Did you have some interesting references about this topic (check post update)?

Comment: A little different approach, but an interesting one to know about:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/heterogeneous-cells-in.html

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you can do it in one of the following ways:

1. Since you said your screens and behaviors are the same, you can use the same class MyListViewController and while creating the instance you can assign/populate the "list" array. That is the conventional approach
2. Alternatively, if your classes (Categories, Recipes, Ingredients) vary slightly in behaviour, you can  sub-class them to MyListViewContrller.  You can do this in .h file like this:

   @interface CategoriesViewController : MyListViewController{

In Xcode, you can select the super-class while you create new class file too.

Hope this helps in some way

Comment: I've already created tre subclasses of `MyListViewController`. Now I wish to customize the behaviour of each one in the proper way. Should I use massive self-calling methods like `[self didFinishDoingSomething]` in the super class? Read my comment in @Joride answer for more information. Ty!

Comment: The concept is like this:  All generic behaviors (methods) and properties should be on the super class (in your case MyListViewController).  Additional properties can be added for sub-classes if needed.  Additional behaviors will come in two different ways: a) additional methods and b) same methods overriding in sub-classes.  Overriding is a slightly big topic for this comment.  I hope you are in sync on that.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So what I've tried to do, calling a method like `[self didFinishDoingSomething]` in the super class and overriding the same method in subclass is well-designed code, okay.